# Android Nine-patch image error

Tags: android, nine-patch

according to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) description I just created an nine-patch image. I named it **androidRow.9.png**.

When I copy it to the `res/drawable` folder I get an error

```
res\drawable\androidRow.9.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using uppercase is incorrect android_row.9.png

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use capital letters. Thus try this: androidrow.9.png.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Android resource does not support UPPERCASE on the name (included image file, xml file, raw file,...)